# Laravel 5.2 : where can I find out the verbosity level now?

Tags: symfony, debugging, console, laravel-5

Talking about laravel console commands. They use Symfony Command, and I found out that it was possible to access to Symfony Command to retrieve the value of verbosity level set at command declaration (i.e. -v or -vv or -vvv values=1,2,3 very useful to show out other stuff on stdout for debugging purposes....)

Before I was able to access the desired property through this line of code:

```
 $this->verbosityLevel = $this->getOutput()->getVerbosity();
```

Now (Lrlv 5.2+) it seems like $this->getOutput() returns null.

How to do it now?

Thanks